# Get the private field by properties with reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, field, private

On my job I work with a v2.0 project. 
I need know which is the private field that is related to each property

```
class Foo {

private string _bar;
public string BigBar
{
    get { return _bar; }
}}
```

Someone know how can I check this relation with reflection

Comment: This cannot be done via reflection. And probably you shouldn't need it.

Comment: `public string Evil { get { return _foo + _bar; } }`

Comment: `public string MoreEvil { get { return rand.NextDouble() < .5 ? _foo : _bar; } }`

Comment: @SLaks, second one is simple, reflection just has to have another instance of `Random` which will help to guess which field was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for backing fields of [auto-like-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), then the only way is to look at the generated IL, with a tool like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), for example.

You'll have to look for a specific IL pattern, and also have to check if the backing field is only used in the property, and nowhere else.

The pattern would be the generated IL for this chunk of code:

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo { get { return _foo; } set { _foo = value; } }
```

(`get` and `set` are optional, but at least one must be present)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a decompiler to see the internal working of the classes:

[Decompilers](http://www.google.nl/search?q=c@%20decompiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=nl&client=firefox-a&hs=hbk&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=c#%20decompiler&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=172180c95e752f9d&biw=1384&bih=768)

Answer (score 0):

While you could only do this with Reflection for Auto-implemented properties, consider using this open-source decompilation library: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx.  You can decompile the relevant methods and see what they do.